# Почему JSON.parse преобразует массив в объект?

Tags: javascript, json

Столкнулся с особенностью парсинга (либо по незнанию не понимаю от чего так происходит) массива с одной строкой.

Есть у нас массив с json строкой.

```
const arr = ['{"name": "John"}']; // массив
const parsedArr = JSON.parse(arr);
console.log(parsedArr); // объект
```

Почему массив преобразовался в объект?

Ещё примеров:

```
const example1 = ['"item"'];
console.log(JSON.parse(example1)); // 'item'

const example2 = ['["item"]'];
console.log(JSON.parse(example2)); // ['item']
```

Кажется, внутри метода parse идёт проверка на то, является ли переданный аргумент массивом. И если да, то если в массиве всего один элемент, то массив раскрывается и возвращается именно элемент массива.

Comment: массив не преобразовался он как был массивом так и остался. parsedArr это результат функции она вернула объект - вы и видите объект

Comment: @IvaMuxa вопрос как раз в том, почему результат преобразования - объект

Comment: вы начистили картошки и выполнили функцию "потолочь" получилось пюре примерно так же

Comment: @IvaMuxa от примера с картошкой яснее не стало) повторюсь: я парсю массив со строкой. Я ожидал на выходе получить массив, либо ошибку. Но метод преобразовал массив с одной json строкой в объект, как будто внутри он раскрыл массив и вытащил оттуда json.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тут ошибка в неявном преобразовании типов.

`JSON.parse` ожидает на вход строку. Соответственно входящий аргумент преобразуется в строку, `['{"name": "John"}'].toString()` === `{"name": "John"}`.

В свою очередь это валидный JSON, который успешно парсится в объект.

То есть

```js
const arr = ['{"name": "John"}']; // массив
const parsedArr = JSON.parse(arr);
console.log(parsedArr); // объект
```

То же самое что и

```js
const arr = ['{"name": "John"}']; // массив
const arrString = ['{"name": "John"}'].toString();
console.log(arrString, typeof arrString); // строка
const parsedArr = JSON.parse(arrString);
console.log(parsedArr, typeof parsedArr); // объект
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)